# How to upgrade my git to latest version

Tags: 14.04, apt, git, atom

running: 
ubuntu 14.04 trusty 64bit.

My current version is:

```
itamar /v/l/a/lists λ git --version
git version 1.9.1
```

I tried: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install git` and it didn't work.

I tried: `sudo apt-get purge git; sudo apt-get install git` and still it installed 1.9.1.

not just that, somehow it uninstalled Atom and Nylas along with git and some other git related packages. I would love to know why it did that also. Below is the output from the purge process.

```
itamar ~ λ sudo apt-get purge git
[sudo] password for itamar: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
atom* git* git-cola* git-core* gitk* nylas*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 543 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 332614 files and directories currently      installed.)
Removing atom (1.8.0) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing atom, directory    '/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm' not empty so not removed
Removing nylas (0.4.49) ...
Purging configuration files for nylas (0.4.49) ...
Removing git-cola (1.9.3-1) ...
Purging configuration files for git-cola (1.9.3-1) ...
Removing gitk (1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3) ...
Removing git-core (1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3) ...
Removing git (1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3) ...
Purging configuration files for git (1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
```

Comment: give  a try `sudo apt-get upgrade git*`

Comment: @Vineet 
got a ton of errors should i post the log ? it's  L-O-N-G!

EDIT:
generally this is the main issue i think -

`Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:`

Comment: please first run `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. Then try to run above command.

Comment: I ran it. i run it before every operation i did.

Comment: take a look @ http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: For explanation, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software), also, when you uninstall something that other packages depend on, those packages are also removed to prevent them from breaking. If you have a really urgent reason to use the latest version of an app, you can compile it yourself, but it's better to use the repo version if possible.

Answer (score 2):

So, I've found that there's a [Ubuntu Git Maintainers team](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) ppa in launchpad. 
Seems legit and it worked, my git is now `2.9`but i really don't see why this wouldn't be included in ubuntu in the first place? this is basic stuff. And don't tell me that it's because i'm running 14.04 and not 16.04 because 14.04 is still the majority of ubuntu users.

It's weird.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software for an explanation.